# Cannot increase MySQL table_open_cache in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, 20.04, systemd

I've read both of these related questions and still stuck:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86987/mysql-open-files-limit-cannot-change-this-variable/86988#86988?newreg=71bfff05b6284cb4be6b5b5cdb6c7f45
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495124/cannot-set-limit-of-mysql-open-files-limit-from-1024-to-65535/35515570#35515570

MySQL table_open_cache is set to `8000` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and this value is not defined in any of the other loaded cnf files:

```
table_open_cache = 8000
```

Also, in `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` I have the default entry:

```
LimitNOFILE=10000
```

When I query variables from the cli I still get this:

```
mysql> show variables like 'table_open_cache';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| table_open_cache | 4745  |
+------------------+-------+
```

Also there's this:

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
```

Which is confusing because if the open files limit was being restricted by system shouldn't I be capped at 1024 instead of 4745?  I don't understand where 4745 is even coming from.

Can someone please explain what's going on here? Is this a MySQL configuration problem or a limit being imposed by the operating system? I just migrated from Ubuntu 16.04 with nearly identical config and this was not a problem before.

OS is Ubuntu 20.04. MySQL version is 8.0.20.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered something that will provide at least a partial answer to my question.  The `LimitNOFILE` setting inside `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` *does play a role here* but unlike other environments I've worked in, the setting is *not a 1:1 relationship* and needs to be much higher than your target `table_open_cache` limit.

Through trial and error, I found that increasing `LimitNOFILE` only results in some fraction of the value being delegated to the `table_open_cache` limit, so I did a bit of experimenting and arrived at this:

- `LimitNOFILE` of `1310` gets the first `400` to `table_open_cache`
- Above `1310`, `table_open_cache` increases by 50% for each `LimitNOFILE`
- Mysteriously, if `LimitNOFILE` is below `510`, `table_open_cache` appears to be uncapped by systemd.

Using the above I got the following equation:

```
(($table_open_cache - 400) * 2) + 1310 = $LimitNOFILE
```

So if you want `table_open_cache` of `8000`, you'd need to set `LimitNOFILE` to `16510`:

```
((8000 - 400) * 2) + 1310 = 16510
```

I can't make heads or tails of what's going on here but I was able to reproduce the same exact behaviour on different hosts with different databases and mysqld configurations.

If someone can provide an authoritative explanation of the reason behind all of this, I will be happy to accept the answer and award a second round of bounty.

Answer (score 1):

The question is outdated and probably answered for most of the readers. But I'd like to add two things: @eaten-by-a-grue wonders why the the limit for open files `LimitNOFILE` needs to be much higher than the `table_open_cache`.

The answer is rather simple, depending on your storage engine, one table consists of multiple files. `table.frm` and `table.ibd` for MyISAM, for example.

Also, I found this very good guide how to increase the `table_open_cache`: https://www.basezap.com/guide-to-raise-ulimit-open-files-and-mysql-open-files-limit/

**Bonus information**

Instead of changing `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` it might make more sense to add a file `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf` and put the updated configuration there, as described on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41906929/4720094). Otherwise your configuration changes might be overwritten by updates.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You have some kind of constraint between `open_files_limit` and `table_open_cache`  and `max_connections` .

For each connection you need a file descriptor and for each table in the cache you need 1 or 2 files descriptor .

If you are not bellow or above some boundaries  the formula will be

***table_cache_size = (requested_open_files - 10 - max_connections) / 2***

All theses parameters are computed in these 3 functions .

function `adjust_table_cache_size`

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/7d10c82196c8e45554f27c00681474a9fb86d137/sql/mysqld.cc#L7717

function `adjust_max_connections`

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/7d10c82196c8e45554f27c00681474a9fb86d137/sql/mysqld.cc#L7704

function `adjust_open_files_limit`

from  https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/7d10c82196c8e45554f27c00681474a9fb86d137/sql/mysqld.cc#L7663

---

In you case you need to increase the max `open_files` to a bigger value .

1) run the command `systemctl edit mysql` and this

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=20000
```

2) systemctl stop mysql

3) systemctl start mysql

Check the new value of max open files

1. **MYSQL WAY to check**

Default value when you installed mysql-server-8.0 on Ubntu 20.4

```
mysql> show global variables like '%open_files_limit%'  ;
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| open_files_limit | 20000 |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In this documentation you will find a formula to compute the right way to set this value .

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit

2. **GENERIC WAY to check**

   - identify the process id of your mysql daemon
   - check the output of `/proc/THE_PID/limits` by running

   `cat /proc/THE_PID/limits | grep -e '^Limit' -e open`

---

And after check your `opencache`

```
mysql> show variables like '%open_cache%'  ;
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| table_open_cache           | 8000  |
| table_open_cache_instances | 16    |
+----------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: @billynoah i updated my answers

Comment: @billynoah i reupdated my answers